# Set the file extension of the temp file

Tags: actionscript-3, air

In AIR there is the `File.createTempFile()` method [docs](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html).

Is there a way to change the extension?

Code so far:

```
var webpage:File = File.createTempFile();
webpage.extension = "html"; // Property is read-only
```

Comment: The point to it? Temp file is a temporary stream-type storage that frees you from few **minor** troubles. You can, as well, create a new file at **File.applicationStorageDirectory** location (that is an always-permitted operation on any platform) with the random-generated name in order to avoid overwriting any existing file and extension of your choosing.

Comment: @Organis How do I manually create the random name in the app storage directory? I don't see this mentioned anywhere.

Comment: There's no default method for that, right, but it is easy to create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: no.

You're even not able to set the filename by yourself. As soon as you call `File.createTempFile();` it will create a file like **fla8121.tmp** which is composed of the prefix 'fla' a random 4-digit hex number and finally the '.tmp' file extension.

On windows this file will be created in `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Temp\`

If you want to create a temporary file on your own, you need to do it like this:

```
    var file:File = File.cacheDirectory.resolvePath("test.html");
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.writeUTFBytes("<html>This is a test</html>");
    stream.close();
```

This will create **test.html** in the same directory as `createTempFile()`